# Mutual Permutation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, permutation, combinatorics

I have a set of elements, say

> a1,b1,b2.

Here, a and b belong to two classes of elements, respectively. I want an algorithm to list all arrangements between these two classes. For example,

> {a1 b1}, {a1 b2}, {b1 a1}, {b2 a1}.

Note that,

1)the arrangements among elements in the same class should be avoided,

2)the number of classes may larger than 2, and

3)the number of elements belonging to different classes may not be identical.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not overly concerned with efficiency, you can do something like (Python)

```
def mutualperms(lst, prefix=()):
    if lst:
        for x in lst:
            yield from mutualperms([y for y in lst if not sameclass(x, y)],
                                   prefix + (x,))
    else:
        yield prefix
```

(If you're unfamiliar with Python generators, think of `yield` as `print` and ignore the `yield from`.)

Here's a Java version.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MutualPerms {
    private static boolean sameClass(String arg1, String arg2) {
        return arg1.charAt(0) == arg2.charAt(0);
    }

    private static void mutualPerms(Deque<String> prefix,
                                    Collection<String> args) {
        if (args.isEmpty()) {
            for (String arg: prefix) {
                System.out.print(arg);
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            for (String arg1: args) {
                prefix.addLast(arg1);
                Collection<String> subargs = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String arg2: args) {
                    if (!sameClass(arg1, arg2)) {
                        subargs.add(arg2);
                    }
                }
                mutualPerms(prefix, subargs);
                prefix.removeLast();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mutualPerms(new LinkedList<String>(), Arrays.asList(args));
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidEisenstat , thanks. Could you please shed some more light on the term of `prefix`? I cannot quite follow you on its exact meaning.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat , thanks. Since I have very rare knowledge about Python, I cannot quite follow you on the usage of the terms of `prefix` and `(x,)`. Could you please shed some more light on how to implement these two terms by kindly showing some more codes or pseudocodes?

Comment: @user3167843 I hope Java is OK.

Answer (score 2):

you can use python's itertools.product to do this:

```
import itertools as itl
la = ['a1']
lb = ['b1', 'b2']
print list(itl.chain(itl.product(la, lb), itl.product(lb, la)))
```

output is:

```
[('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'b2'), ('b1', 'a1'), ('b2', 'a1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

For case where k = 2 (number of classes):

1) match first element from K1 with every element in K2

2) for each such match create all permutations

3) add all permutations to the final list

4) continue with remaining elements in K1

For case where k > 2 you need to extend this so that you first take the first element from K1, first element in K2 and then the remaining in K3 (or first in K3 and continue with K4,..,Kn).